# How to remove a single data which is store in a single key in ionic storage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to make a note app with ionic, where I am using a storage plugin.

I set a key like this:

```
  private note: note[] = [];

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {

  }

  addNote(note: note) {
    this.note.push(note);
    this.storage.set('note', this.note);
  }


getNote() {
    return this.storage.get('note')
    .then(
        (note) => {
            this.note= note== null ? [] : note;
            return this.note.slice();
        }
    )
  }
```

Where all the data is an array object, like this:

```
(3) [Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
length:3
```

I just want to remove a single array object inside this note array. 
I tried `this.storage.remove(note[index]);` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get the value.
2. slice the exact object.
3. rewrite the new value to the storage.

   try something like

```
storage.get('note').then((note) => {
    note.splice(index, 1);   // i don't know what is index refer to
    storage.set('note', note);
  });
```

Comment: but, I need to remove object.

Comment: @pclover you need to remove object form the note array ? this code remove a object at position `index` inside the array

Answer (score 0):

```
let index = note.indexOf(value);
if(index > -1)
{
  storage.get('note').then((note) => {
    note.splice(index, 1); 
    storage.set('note', note);
  });
}
```